# Xcode beta simulator loads to black

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I just updated both Xcode and Mac OS to the beta for other purposes, but now when I run my project, it states that is has succeeded, but only will show a black screen on the simulator. I have tried quitting restarting etc, does anyone else know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a bug in your app?

Comment: Are you able to use the simulator for things other than your app?  Safari, etc?